# what is the very last function call in magento when going though the checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

i have created a session which store data for when a customer is editing an order, when a customer goes though the checkout this session needs to be unset at some point cause it's existence is an indication that an order is being edited

now while i've been able to find the payment gateway and put the unset syntax there i have ran into a problem, 1 customer group has access to reward points while another doesn't, both can edit their orders

naturally, when a customer processes their order that they've been editing, their points change depending on the difference between this order and the original one, that i can do with the data stored in this session but i can't access the session if it's removed at the payment gateway as it seems that the payment gateway is processed before the rewards points are

so what is the very last function call made by magento during the checkout process, it needs to be one that is accessed by anyone going though the checkout